# Extract data from a table only for entries created in current year

Tags: mysql, extract, record

I have this query to extract exam participants from a table

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM course_participants 
 WHERE course_id = courses.id) AS 'totalParticipants'
```

The table has a column `created` of `DATETIME` datatype; here the date/time of creation date is stored for each participant (for example 2019-01-09 15:51:32).

How can I modify the `SELECT` query to extract records created only in 2019?

Thanks!

Comment: do you want only count ?

Comment: I am guessing that the table has a column called `created` that is a DATETIME Datatype

Comment: Does that query work? Is that the complete query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract year from query as follows,

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM course_participants WHERE course_id = courses.id 
and YEAR(created) = 2019) as 'totalParticipants'
```

Here is official [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/year.html) for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your WHERE clause:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM course_participants 
 WHERE course_id = courses.id 
     AND YEAR(yourDateTimeColumn) = 2019
```

Answer (score 0):

---

In your database add a column with the name year (for example).

And

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM course_participants WHERE course_id = courses.id) and year(created) = 2019) as 'totalParticipants'
```

Enjoy coding !

Comment: ? You didnt add a column called year, you used the `year()` function on the existing dateand time  column called `created`

Comment: if he do,'t have one he have to do that :)